# My phone suddenly shows an SD-card notification

Tags: external-sd, sony-xperia-j

My Sony Xperia J phone was in my pocket and I wanted to read an ebook, so started my reader application. It showed a black screen and when I checked the shelf, all my books were gone.

I noticed a new notification icon that looked like a folded SD card. I checked its message that said: **SD card is empty or its file system is not supported**.

What? Half an hour ago I was using it.
I tapped the message and a question appeared: *Do you want to format your SD-card? It'll erase all data from it.*

What?? All my ebooks and media are gone just like that?

I restarted the phone, still no SD-card. When I got home, I removed the card and reinserted and fortunately now it works.

How does that so-called OS dare to lose my data? And the "recovery" solution is to *format the card*?

What could cause this?

Comment: This is 99% more likely to be a hardware issue (your SD card) than a software issue (the "so-called OS").  The suggestion to format the card is not a recovery suggestion, obviously.  It's saying the card needs formatting as it cannot be read (it appears unformatted, due to a fault with the SD card).

Comment: As Archer stated: it's rather your so-called SD card which very likely will give up on you soon. I'd backup its contents ASAP and get a new one.

Comment: My experiences with this so-called platform are very ambiguous. My phone keeps forgetting the sound settings, can't change from Wifi to 3G sometimes. It's like a bad joke.

Comment: @Nestor A word of advice, if I may.  Stow the negative attitude.  You're on a Q&A site for Android enthusiasts.  You may receive a more sympathetic response if you don't slate the thing that they love that has brought them here.  It's not constructive and you can post without it.  Not getting into a debate about it - just saying.  I hope you get your problem resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my family members had the same problem, SD card misbehaving, then working for a few days, on and off. After a week or so the phone did not read the card at all and neither did the PC. Fortunately I backed up the content of the card after the first problem. The card worked for about a month after formatting, but died eventually.

I do not know what causes this.
I do not know how to stop it.
I know what you should do: a **backup**.